# fog in unity with c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get fog to get denser over time in unity3d with c# script

in start i turn it on as following code shows

```
 void Start () {
    RenderSettings.fog =true;
    RenderSettings.fogDensity = 0.00f;
 }
```

in update i check every 3 seconds and add to density as following code shows

```
 void Update () {
      StartCoroutine(updateTheFog());
 }
```

and the updateTheFog function is

```
IEnumerator updateTheFog(){

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3); 

    RenderSettings.fogDensity+=0.01f;
}
```

the problem is that it waits for the 3 seconds and then just automatically goes to 1.0 instead of going incremently by 0.01 every 3 seconds

Any help getting this worked out is appreciated

Comment: I think it's because the `Update` routine is called every frame, and each one spins up a new coroutine waiting for 3 seconds. So if your game's `Update` runs 60+ times a second, then your fog density will skyrocket pretty fast.

Comment: What if you tried replacing it with: `void Update() { RenderSettings.fogDensity += 0.01f * (Time.deltaTime / 3); }`? That will increment the `fogDensity` every frame at (I think) the same rate you intended initially.

Answer (score 4):

As per [THIS](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/375656/execute-coroutine-in-update.html) question, you should NOT use Update for this, because Update runs once every frame and cannot be delayed. Instead of doing this, what you could do is instead start the coroutine in Start() and use a `while(true)` infinite loop to repeat this manually.

```
void Start () 
{
    RenderSettings.fog =true;
    RenderSettings.fogDensity = 0.00f;
    StartCoroutine(updateTheFog());
}

IEnumerator updateTheFog() 
{
    while(true)
    { 
        //this makes the loop itself yield 
        return new WaitForSeconds(3); 

        RenderSettings.fogDensity+=0.01f;
    }
    //if you want to stop the loop, use: break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What Lee Taylor said should work but as an alternative you could use the InvokeRepeating function witch allows you to set a function to be called at certain time intervals kinda like the timers in the .net framework.  you can even stop the invokereapeating by calling CancelInvoke.

```
void Start(){
    InvokeRepeating("updateTheFog",3,3);
}
void updateTheFog(){
// do your fog stuff
if(fogDensity == 1)
    cancleInvoke()
 }
```